# Running pre-commit on all files in git beyond HEAD

Tags: git, pre-commit.com

I have already made `git commit`s, but want to re-run `pre-commit` on files above a current Git HEAD commit.  I intend to do this in CI with a second, more feature-full `pre-commit` configuration called `.pre-commit-other-config.yaml`.

I can accomplish this like so:

```sh
git show --name-only --format="" HEAD | pre-commit run --config .pre-commit-other-config.yaml
```

I am wondering: is there a built-in option for this in `pre-commit`?

**Asides**

I am not interested in all files (`pre-commit run -a`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

surprised you [didn't check the docs for `pre-commit run`](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-run)

you're looking for `--from-ref` and `--to-ref`

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Thank you again @AnthonySottile, you've done an excellent job with `pre-commit`!